# Open multiple links as tabs

Tags: jquery

I need a script that is designed to open all links in a particular element and I need them to open in a new tab.  I have the following code which opens all the links but in new windows and not in tabs.

Is it possible to do this?

```
$('#result_list tbody a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('target', '_blank');
    $this.get(0).click(function() {
        window.open(this);
        window.focus();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Please, please, please [don't use target = _blank](http://www.thatwebguyblog.com/post/dont_use_target_blank/).  If your users want the content in a new window they will open it in a new window.  Let them make that choice.  That being said, as far as I know, you have no control over how creating tabs and windows are created.  That is determined by the settings in the user's browser.  Some browsers don't even tabs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need the target="_blank" attribute. `window.open`, by default,  open in a new window. Most of modern browser will open the link into a new tab instead of a new window.

```
$('#result_list tbody a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.get(0).click(function() {
        window.open(this);
        window.focus();
        return false;
    });
});
```

On which browser have you tried?

Comment: This does not work for me in chrome. When automatically triggering more clicks, then only the first link is opened in a new tab, the others in popups.

Comment: I have the same problem and it doesn't work for me either. The solution works in Firefox. But in Chrome, it only opens the first link.

Comment: Sorry, I just figured it out. Chrome just blocks multiple popups automatically and asks the user if he wants to open the next (or unblock popups for the whole website). Sadly, the Chrome's question is just a tiny button in the address bar so the user usually doesn't notice it.